# PHP and regex101.com have different result

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have created a regular expression.

> ([a-zA-Z<][/a-zA-Z0-9> .?!,;_<'\n-]*)[ |\n][0-9]*[ |\n]

I would like to use it on a subtitle file.
e.g.:

> 65 00:04:33,417 --> 00:04:35,658 But I quit my old job so I could be
>   with you.
>
> 66 00:04:35,937 --> 00:04:36,984 Do you miss it?
>
> 67 00:04:41,217 --> 00:04:42,423 No, I like my new job.

When I use this regex on regex101 or regexr.com then it works properly.
But when I use in my PHP code then they have a different results.

```
$myString=file_get_contents("wwz.srt");
$formula="/([a-zA-Z<][\/a-zA-Z0-9> .?!,;_<'\n-]*)[ |\n][0-9]*[ |\n]/";
preg_match_all($formula, $myString, $matches);
```

There is a part of the subtitle:

> 70 00:04:49,017 --> 00:04:50,348 Look who I found!
>
> 71 00:04:49,017 --> 00:04:50,348 Here comes the number 12 train!
>
> 72 00:04:50,417 --> 00:04:51,782 It's not Subway Sam, is it?
>
> 73 00:04:52,337 --> 00:04:54,578 You want more pancakes?
>
> 74 00:04:55,177 --> 00:04:56,542 Good.
>
> 75 00:04:56,697 --> 00:04:58,984 Go, go, go. Come on, scootch!
>
> 76 00:04:59,057 --> 00:05:00,821
>   - At least...
>   - Move it on out.
>
> 77 00:05:00,897 --> 00:05:02,786 Hey! Plates in the sink!
>
> 78 00:05:02,857 --> 00:05:04,018
>   - Later!
>   - Do that when we get back!

If I use this example in the regex101, this will be the first result:

> Look who I found! 71

If I use this example in my php code with the same regex, this will be the first result:

> Here comes the number 12

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you escape the characters - especially the backslash - properly ?

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/qY5uW0/1) what you want to get?

Comment: After the suggestion I have tried the escape, but the problem still exists. And stribizhev: yes, I would like to get that result.

Comment: It is not true, [look at my demo](http://ideone.com/O8IyB8). The first submatch (captured text) is `Look who I found!
`

Answer (score 4):

When you copy a crafted regex from regex101.com in order to use it in your program you should use the code generator because it ensures that characters are escaped properly for being used in a string.
In addition to this you have to make sure that you choose the correct flavor, because you might get a regex that is working online with regex101 but not inside your program because it uses a different regex engine.

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to escape `\n`

Comment: I tried that and pasted the regex from code generator into my code but the problem still exists.

Comment: I have modified the question. Please check the extension, maybe it will be more descriptive what is my problem.